# apk file not running on lower api ,cordova 5.0

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed app using cordova platform 5.0 which requires at least android api level 14, how can i make it run for other smaller api running phones, i ahve tried editing the AndroidManifest file by making minandroidverion as : 9, and then try building again using ionic , it is not allowing me.

Comment: Simple... don't use Cordova 5.0.

Comment: Supporting an api version that old might provide a lot of challenges.  Cordova 3.x up to 4 supported as low as 10. 2.x supports level 8.  It is likely that 2.x won't work with Ionic's tools.  See: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide if you're interested in using 2.x